# What is the right way to solve the MemoryException for numpy?

Tags: numpy, out-of-memory

During calculations in my program a generate numpy arrays several times with pcr2numpy tool of PCRaster. For some rasters it worked, but now I get

```
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 140. MiB for an array with shape (7411, 4969) and data type float32
```

What is the real reason of this, and what should I do: delete arrays just after use, or use arrays with more NaN values?

Here is a part of code where the problem appears:

```
allpoints = cover(firstpoints1,secondpoints)
allpoints2 = ifthen(allpoints,self.upstreamup)
array1 = pcr2numpy(allpoints2,np.nan)
array2 = pcr2numpy(ifthen(allpoints, newpointts),np.nan)
array10 = array1[~np.isnan(array1)]
array20 = array2[~np.isnan(array2)]
meann = np.nanmean(array2)
```

cover is a command for union of two rasters where NaN values are replaced
ifthen is a command which takes only True values and everything else makes NaN values
pcr2numpy makes a numpy array from a raster

Comment: Deleting arrays should help. Using more NaN does not. You can use a smaller float type like `np.float32` which is also less accurate but this seems to be already the case. You can also use the `out` parameter of some functions to reuse some buffer. If this is not enough you can use Numba or Cython to perform the computation at once (using less temporary buffers). If this is still not enough, you can read/write chunks of data if possible (but this is tricky to do). If this is not enough, then the input may be to big or you may need to kill processes that take a lot of RAM.

Comment: Usually we see MemoryErrors when trying to create and use GiB arrays, since modern RAM is measured multiples of that.  The MiB size suggests that you already have a lot of arrays in use.  A full traceback might help narrow down the operation that raising the error, But you may also need to take an inventory of all arrays in use at that point.